# How to compile material components web react example

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I tried this example of Material Components for the web:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/framework-examples/react

I can use it with node installed locally but I don't know how to compile it to test the code on my server (I don't have node on my server).

Answer (score 2):

The example uses [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) and you can build it for production with:

```
npm run build
```

This creates a directory `build` which is self-contained. All you need to do is host it on your server. You don't need to have Node installed on the server, nor do you need any other file of the project. This is one of the main selling points of webpack.